# Should I always use MaterialApp as the parent widget of my app?

Tags: android, flutter

I am new in flutter. I am developing an app using it. Is it must that  I should always use MaterialApp as the parent widget of my app? I was mistakenly wrapping
each page of my app by MaterialApp.

Answer (score 2):

That’s the most commonly used, but you can use others like “Cupertino” which is an ios like style.

Answer (score 1):

Some material and cupertino widgets require you to use MaterialApp or CupertinoApp as an ancestor but there is no problem with not using Cupertino/Material design, you can make your own design.

Example:

> This widget also configures the observer of the top-level Navigator (if any) to perform Hero animations.

[MaterialApp class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html)